# How to specify multiple selectors within an iframe using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors, find

There is not nice HTML structure I need to work with and the list of elements I need to select is within an iframe. The problem is that I am interested just in 2 type of divs within many other divs on same level.

I am able to select such a type from the iframe but just one at time:

```
$("#someIframe").contents().find(".class a img[src*='type1']")
```

But I am unable to select both:

```
$("#someIframe").contents().find(".class a img[src*='type1'], .class a img[src*='type2']") -> does not work
```

The problem is that I need to select the first one, but I don't know which one is the first one :) something like:

```
$("#someIframe").contents().find(".class a img[src*='type1'], .class a img[src*='type2']").first()
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I have found another way around. I have noticed that those elements I don't want to select contains specific text:

```
<div>not listed</div>
```

However, again finding the correct selector would be the problem since I need opposite of this below :)

```
$("#someIframe").contents().find(".someclass div:contains('not listed')").first()
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with approach shown, assuming that both selectors exist at the time the code runs

Comment: yes, there are multiple elements that fulfill both selectors at the time the code runs. It's strange, but maybe I will be able to workaround it -> original post

Comment: Give it some logics in the script!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Here is the code if anyone needs it in the future:

```
$("#someIframe").contents().find(".someclass").not($("#someIframe").contents().find(".someclass div:contains('not listed')").parent()).first()
```

It's not nice, but the markup itself is not nice, so I guess it's fine :)